# Shouldn't [read-only] and [readonly] be tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

I can't formally suggest these tag synonyms because I don't have 5 votes in either, but it seems to me that [read-only](/questions/tagged/read-only) and [readonly](/questions/tagged/readonly) should be the same tag.

Comment: As usual, the proper two-word version has fewer questions tagged with it ... sigh.

Comment: @MatthewRead: Probably because `readonly` is a language keyword.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ah, that's fair enough.

Comment: I disagree, I think @Robert's tag wiki edit is what's needed here. `readonly` is indeed a language keyword, and it means something different than "read-only" status might imply on a file.